# Android Java save cookies of a http request

Tags: java, android, http, request

I just found a tutorial where someone explains how to do a http request in an android application. Now I need to save the cookies. It's shown with `PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this)` but I need to do this as `public` so `this` doesn't work :/ 
Can anyone help me what to write instead of this?

Regards,
Phil

PS: The tutorial is here: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorial, PersistentCookieStore needs "context" as an argument. You can do PersistentCookieStore(YourActivity.this) or PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()).
(YourActivity is the activity title.)
Hope this helps.

Thanks

Here is a trivial example.

```
package com.example.fixit;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String TAG="MainActivity";
    private PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
    client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
    client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Log.i(TAG, response);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Hm, I am in MainActivity.java so I tried `MainActivity.this`but it doesnt work: `No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope`and with `getApplicationContext()` it doesnt work either: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper`:/

Comment: It'd be easier for me to help if you post your code. Or, try remove the "static" keyword from your method signature and getApplicationContext should work.

Comment: This is at the beginning of the main activity `public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
 PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext());` and it totally crashes now when I start :/

Comment: Please see my edit and don't forget to add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in the manifest. Let me know if this helps. thanks

Comment: Sure this works, but I put it in 2 functions, 1 for get and 1 for post. And when i recieve cookies for login, I need them all the time. But if I call `PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);` new every time, it won't save the cookies because they will be overwritten or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: From my understanding, you should set it only once.

Comment: Yes but then I have it to set globally. Because when I set it in `oncreate` I can't use it in another function, you know what I mean?

Comment: Move the declaration out of onCreate. Please see my edit. (private PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore;) Let me know if this works.